# Telegram Bot answering FAQ questions

Tags: python, nlp, telegram-bot

I am wondering if it is possible to write a telegram bot that will answer similar to FAQ questions of any chosen website. Since I couldn't find any examples similar to my idea, I've decided to post this question here.

Probably, it is worth using [DialogFlow](https://dialogflow.com) framework here, but, again, there are no examples on the web.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) should be a good start

Comment: @learner, thank you for your answer, but i'm not looking for a telegram-api guide, it seems clear to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the bot myself. The idea is pretty simple: convert questions into word2vec embeddings then use softcosim to measure the distance between the input question and the one from FAQ. You may check out the code [here](https://github.com/etomoscow/FAQ_helper_bot)

Answer (score 2):

Integrating Telegram with Dialogflow is quite easy. You can follow the guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/telegram): basically just make the bot in Telegram and paste the generated access token in the Integrations section in the Dialogflow console. Assuming that it is a basic question and answer format and the responses to the questions are static, meaning the question will have the same answer every time it is asked, you should be able to do this without any code. You can just make an Intent in Dialogflow for each question, give several training phrases for the various ways that it could be worded, and then give the response in the response section.

Answer (score 1):

Just build a qna bot using qnamaker.ai
As soon as it is hosted in Azure, you can activate the Telegram channel. A guide is available on that page that will guide you.
You should be up and running in hours.